# Random number guessing game with if statement and a for loop Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, random

My name is Fermin.  I'm new in this forum and I'm also studying Java to be a Java developer.  I'm stuck on an assignment and I would like some help from anyone.  Here is the description and the  code 
Using an if statement in the for block, determine
whether randNum and guessNum are equal.

```
public class GuessGame {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {


     int randNum , guessNum ;
     //Generates a random number from 1 to 10
     randNum = new java.util.Random().nextInt(10) + 1;
     System.out.println("Im thinking of a number from 1 to 10");

  for (guessNum = 0; guessNum <= 10; guessNum ++){

      java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
      guessNum = scan.nextInt();

      if (guessNum == randNum) {
           System.out.println("you guess" + guessNum );
    }
  } 
}
```

}

**Updated code**

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class NumberGuess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.println("Im thinking of a number from 1 to 10");
        int number = scan.nextInt(10);
         //Generates a random number from 1 to 10
        int number2 = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
        System.out.println("you enter the number" + " " + number);


        for (int counter = -1; counter < 3; counter ++ ){
             if(number!= number2)
               System.out.println("and your random number is:" + " " + number2 + " " + "please try again"); 
             else 
                 System.out.println("your guess number is equal to the random number Good job guessing");

             break;
         }

    }
  }
```

Comment: where is the code, what you tried

Comment: On StackOverflow, if you are requesting help with a piece of code, you must show that code and indicate exactly what trouble you're having with it (and where, specifically, in the code). If you are unclear about the actual problem statement of your assignment, it would probably be best to talk to your teacher.

Comment: This...is...sad......

Comment: public class NumberGuess3 {

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int randNum , guessNum ;
//Generates a random number from 1 to 10
randNum = new java.util.Random().nextInt(10) + 1;
 System.out.println("Im thinking of a number from 1 to 10");

for (guessNum = 0; guessNum <= 10; guessNum ++)
{
  java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
guessNum = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("you guess" + guessNum + "");
  
  if (guessNum == randNum) {
    System.out.println(“You guessed it!”);
break;
  }
} 
    }
}

Comment: Sorry Im all alone in this, I been stock on this assingment for like 4 months. someone please help me

Comment: Don't put code into a comment. Edit your question and put your formatted code there.

Comment: So what specifically is the problem you're having? At a glance it appears  that you've done exactly what you're tasked with doing, no?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I need to create a simple number guessing
game. The game will use a "for statement" to ask for three
guesses and an "if statement" to determine if the answer is
right.

Comment: I don't need a reiteration of the assignment, I am asking what is currently wrong with your implementation, and/or what trouble you're presently having?

Comment: I can't get the for loop to work correctly with the random numbers. and the if statement to compare if the random number is equal to the scan input from the user to output put a println statement. Thanks for you reply again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is controlled by the `guessNum` variable. Within the loop, you're reassigning that variable's value when you do this:

```
guessNum = scan.nextInt();
```

As a result, you're likely getting an inconsistent number of loops because you're changing the variable that the loop relies on for control.

Given the name of this variable, I suspect you originally intended it to be used to store the user's input. If that is the case, I would alter your `for` loop to use a different variable instead, like so:

```
for (int guessCount = 0; guessCount < 10; guessCount++){
```

Also note, your condition originally had `<= 10`; since your counting variable started at zero, this will allow the user 11 guesses, rather than 10 (since 0 to 10 inclusive = 11). Assuming you wanted 10 guesses instead, you will want to check for less than 10 (since 0..10 exclusive = 10).

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, my last questions is how to compare the scan input and the generated random number with the "if statement" to see if they are both equal to print a output statement the tells that user the guess is equal with the random number.Thanks Mr Richter

Comment: @Ferm1974 You're already doing that. You should also have a `break;` inside the if statement, but otherwise that portion of the code should do exactly that.

Comment: Thank Paul for the help you the best, I think I think I finally have the code together let me show you new pseudocode

Comment: @Ferm1974 SO is not a forum with conversation threads; if you want to update your code, edit the question and paste it in there. I've already done so for you, but please do remember for next time. As for the code, looks like you've removed the `scan.nextInt` from the loop for some reason. You'll need that in there.

Answer (score -1):

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class NumberGuess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        System.out.println("Im thinking of a number from 1 to 10");
        int number = scan.nextInt(10);
         //Generates a random number from 1 to 10
        int number2 = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
        System.out.println("you enter the number" + " " + number);


        for (int counter = -1; counter < 3; counter ++ ){
             if(number!= number2)
               System.out.println("and your random number is:" + " " + number2 + " " + "please try again"); 
             else 
                 System.out.println("your guess number is equal to the random number Good job guessing");

             break;
         }

    }
  }
```